# recordmydesktop outputs 1920x1072 instead of 1920x1080, which is what my monitor resolution is

Tags: recordmydesktop

my monitor is 1920x1080, but recordmydesktop records in 1920x1072. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

It seams it can't be fixed. 1080 is not divisible by 16.

see: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=549262

> RecordMyDesktop enforces both coordinates of the offset of the recorded area
>   to be divisible by 2, and of its size to be divisible by 16. These
>   restrictions are not documented. According to comments in the code, they
>   come from MIT-SHM constraints.